# Request assistance with codingbat solution

Tags: python

I am working my way through *Codingbat* *Python* problems and need a bit of help with one called `make_pi`.

> Problem statement:
>
> Return an `int array` length 3 containing the first 3 digits of pi, `{3, 1, 4}`.

I have seen all the answers of others, which is to simply return a list of `[1,2,3]`.  However I don't think that is what the problem is trying to do.  I believe by my reading of the problem it is asking to take pi, which is a float, and then manipulate and return a list of integers only, without the decimal.  I am trying to do this with simple loops and iterations.  I know there are methods, list comprehension, etc. that can do this easily but the point of *Codingbat* is to learn and since no method, etc., are used I think there has to be a simple loop solution. I think you first turn the float into a string, then rebuild the string without the decimal and then return back a resultant int list of `[1,2,3]`. Apologize for the long windedness, but I am trying to learn and could use some help.

```
def make_pi():
    pi = 3.14
    pilist = str(pi)

make_pi()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
def make_pi():  
    a= math.pi
    b=str(round(a,2)) #Round to 2 places & converted to string for slicing 
    c=b[0:1]+b[2:] #To remove the decimal point in 3.14 
    return  [int(x) for x in c] #Convert to integer 
print(make_pi())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_pi():
num = list(str(3.14))
for ans in range(len(num)):
    if num[ans] == '.':
        num.remove(num[ans])
        break
return num
```

Comment: By the things you have said, I changed my code that was returning [3, 1, 4]. So now I am using the iteration loop that you said you were trying to use plus some list functions.

Answer (score 0):

```html
def make_pi():
    pi = 3.14

    pilist =  str(pi) 
    c = []
    for digit in pilist:
        if digit != ".":
            c.append ((digit))     
    d = []    
    for i in c:
        d.append(int(i))
    print d 

 
make_pi() # [3, 1, 4]
```

Thanks for your effort Alexandre but what you ended up with is a str list vice int list.

I think I have been able to solve.  What I did is defined pi first, then made a str list out of it and then iterated to build a new str of int without the decimal.  This then resulted in a new list [3, 1, 4] of ints vice as string characters.
   Hopefully I have entered this properly into the post.

Answer (score 0):

i tried the code below, in jupyter it works but if i tried the same code in codingbat it throws an error.

Basically the code is that it converts 3.14 as string then use a FOR loop to iterate each character, skips the dot then stores all the chars to a new variable at the same time converting each chars to an integer.

```
def make_pi():
    pi = str(3.14)
    new_pi=[]
    
    
    for x in pi:
        if x == '.':
            continue
        else:
            x = int(x)
            new_pi.append(x)
    return new_pi
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def make_pi():
    pi = "3.14"
    pie = [int(a) for a in pi if a != "."]
    return pie
```